# Given the degrees at each vertex, (5,5,4,4,4,3,3) show that this graph exists without drawing it

Tags: graph-theory

So here's what I already know.

# of vertices: 7

# of total degree of graph: 28

# of edges: 14

The total degree must be even which checks out. I'm given the hint to use complementary graphs, but lost on how to proceed. One way I've thought of so far is to assume the complementary graph as $(1,1,2,2,2,3,3)$ in respect to the original graph given. With that I can come up with that the total degree is 14 which means the number of edges in the complementary is 7. But how do i use this information to show that the original graph is actually a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertices with degree 1 form one component of the graph (just two vertices with edge between them), and the sequence $(3,3,2,2,2)$ belongs to $K_{2,3}$ - a complete bipartite graph with sides of sizes 3 and 2. 
You can also use Havel-Hakimi theorem that provides a simple [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) to the decide whether a degree sequence is graphic or not.

Comment: So, using the complementary graph, 

(3,3,2,2,2,1,1) <-> (2,1,1,1,1,0) <-> (0,0,0,0,0) which is a graph because they're just vertices without any edges? Using the havel-hakimi algorithmas @kotomord used and as you mentioned

Comment: The sequence should be (3,3,2,2,2,1,1) <-> (2,1,1,1,1,1) <-> (0,0,1,1,1) [sort to (1,1,1,0,0)] <-> (0,0,0,0) which is graph without edges.

Comment: why isn't the first 1 in the first sequence from (3,3,2,2,2,1,1) subtracted to 0?

Comment: According to the algorithm, you subtract 1 only from the second element up to the $d_1 + 1$ element in the sequence.  In this case, $d_1$ is 3, so you subtract 1 from $d_2$,$d_3$ and $d_4$. The rest, in this case $d_5$, $d_6$ and $d_7$ should remain the same.

Comment: Ah from what i just searched, i was doing the degree sequence algorithm, but I think both eventually end up at the same answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(5,5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3) <-> (4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2) <-> (2, 2, 2, 2, 2) 
Last graph exists (it a simple cycle)

Comment: is this the steps in the havel-hakimi algorithm? 
If so, could you just help me walk through the steps?
the 4 is from 5-4, and the 3s are from 4-1? and the last one is the same?

Comment: No, it is simple greedy. 
I get the vertice with the maximal degree (n) and decrease to 1 degrees from the next n vertices (sorted by degree in descending order)